# Mention a numerical metric with Plotly line maps

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to plot five rail routes in Germany with plotly line_mapbox function. I am able to plot all five routes. However, I also want to mention the avg. delay caused in each route, either in text format or assigning colours to each route based on a heatmap (where delay would define the heatmap range). Is it possible with plotly line maps? My current map is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you generated this map, with plotly.express or plotly.graph_objects.
In px you can assign a color to each trace by simply defining color=[column] in the graph function call. In go you should assign a color to each trace individually by changing the line color via the mode setting or update_traces (https://plotly.com/python/reference/scattermapbox/).

In px you can also add text=[column] in the call to add text annotations.